# pdf of the minimum of two dependent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I am struggling at calculating the pdf of the minimum of two random variables as follows:
$v = \min(v_1 + k_1 \cdot v_3, v_2 + k_2 \cdot v_3)$

where:

- $v$: continuous random variable I want to know the pdf
- $v_1$: continuous random variable of given pdf $pv_1(v_1)$
- $v_2$: continuous random variable of given pdf $pv_1(v_2)$ (not a typo, same pdf as $v_1$)
- $v_3$: continuous random variable of given pdf $pv_3(v_3)$
- $k_1$: real number
- $k_2$: real number

Even when considering the particular case $k_1 = k_2$, I can't find a solution.
Can anyone be of help?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but if the variables are dependent then it is not enough to know their marginal pdf's, you also need joint pdf's.

Comment: To clarify, v1, v2 and v3 are independent, but v1+k1.v3 and v2+k2.v3 are inherently dependent.